# Elasticsearch bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, boolean

I was following the guide here https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries and the bool query below confuses me:

```js
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool" : { "should": [
                      { "match": { "title": "Elasticsearch" }},
                      { "match": { "title": "Solr" }} ] }
            },
            "must": { "match": { "authors": "clinton gormely" }},
            "must_not": { "match": {"authors": "radu gheorge" }}
        }
    }
}
```

According to the tutorial, the explanation of the query is:

> Search for a book with the word “Elasticsearch” OR “Solr” in the title,
>   AND is authored by “clinton gormley” but NOT authored by “radu
>   gheorge”

My question is, there are 3 conditions but also 3 logical operator in the bool query (must, must, must_not) instead of 2. My understanding is that 3 conditions should only have 2 logical operator like `COND1 AND COND2 AND !COND3`.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

That query is wrong and will not work, it is not possible to have two `bool/must` clauses, they must be merged like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": "Elasticsearch"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": "Solr"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "authors": "clinton gormley"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "authors": "radu gheorge"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the reason why the `bool/should` clause is burried inside the  `bool/must` one is to give and equal weight to the match on `authors` than the two matches on the `title`.

Comment: But I tried the examples and it worked fine. Any idea why? ES 5.x BTW

Comment: How did you try them? via Kibana? There's no way the above query **AS IS** can yield anything.

Comment: Unfortunately they did. I am using curl tho.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, except that two `must` in the same `bool` is not correct. Docs and article bugs do exist :-)

Comment: Your query makes perfect sense to me, it just confuses me why the query on the tutorial links works even on latest ES 5.3. BTW is it working for you on your ES installation?

Comment: The query is not wrong per se, however, when ES parses it, it will remove one of the two `must` clause since a JSON document is basically a hash and hashes cannot contain the same key twice at the same level. So I think the query works because the document matches solely on the author field and there's no constraint on the title field

Comment: I thought one of the must clause will be removed too, but that is not the case. Both conditions did get applied after several tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142263/discussion-between-steve-and-val).

Comment: any resolution of that? Also how to create "(con1 OR con2) AND (con3 OR con4)" in that case?